# How to get a list of children from a SharePoint list item using msgraph v1.0 with Python?

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Yesterday my code stopped working to retrieve a list of files from a folder. Before that everything was ok and running into a Python script.

The scenario is as follows: the folder is an item from a SharePoint list. I was getting the fields: id, name, createdDateTime, parentReference, folder, file about the children of the folder/item using a request to msgraph API and now I'm getting the error 400 for bad request.

The URL I was using is: [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{domain}:/sites/{alias}:/lists/{list_id}/items/{number_item}/driveItem/children?$select=id,name,createdDateTime,parentReference,folder,file](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bdomain%7D:/sites/%7Balias%7D:/lists/%7Blist_id%7D/items/%7Bnumber_item%7D/driveItem/children?$select=id,name,createdDateTime,parentReference,folder,file)

The folder still exists with the same number, and nothing has changed within the folder in terms of file structure or names. Token is right. `Number_item` is right and all the variables.

This is what I've been receiving from the request since yesterday with code 400 bad request.

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "invalidRequest",
        "message": "Invalid request"
    }
}
```

I've already tried:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{domain}:/sites/{alias}:/lists/{list_id}/items/{number_item}/driveItem/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bdomain%7D:/sites/%7Balias%7D:/lists/%7Blist_id%7D/items/%7Bnumber_item%7D/driveItem/children)

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{domain}:/sites/{alias}:/lists/{list_id}/items/{number_item}/children](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bdomain%7D:/sites/%7Balias%7D:/lists/%7Blist_id%7D/items/%7Bnumber_item%7D/children)

All returned bad request code 400.

I also tried using it with `driveId` but without success.

I've tried:
[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{dommain}:/sites/{site}:/lists/{list_id}/items/{nummber_item}/driveItem?$expand=listItem](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bdommain%7D:/sites/%7Bsite%7D:/lists/%7Blist_id%7D/items/%7Bnummber_item%7D/driveItem?$expand=listItem)

but does not return the list of files and folder that are into my `number_item` (that is a folder).

Does anyone know if anything has changed in the msgraph API? or maybe point out where I'm wrong?

Comment: I found this site: Microsoft Graph changelog. My error started after a change by Microsoft in the driveItem item. However, according to the documentation, the list children method is still available. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveItem?view=graph-rest-beta